# Webpack not reading @ symbol - Unexpected character '@' (4:0)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Why am I receiving this error? I also have bootstrap files being imported into the main custom.scss file.  Not sure if this is creating any issues?

I'm receiving this error when attempting to use the scss loader in 
            webpack:

```
        Unexpected character '@' (4:0)
        You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
        | 
        | 
        | @import "_bootstrap"; 
        | @import "spinner"; 
        | @import "navigations";
         @ ./js/app.js 5:0-30



        Here is my webpack.config.js script:

        var path = require('path');
        var webpack = require('webpack');

        module.exports = {
            entry: './js/app.js',
            output: {
                path: __dirname,
                filename: 'js/bundle.js'
            },

            watch: true,
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                        //test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                        use: 'file-loader'
                    }
                ],
                loaders: [
                    {
                    test: /.jsx?$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                    }
                  },
                  {
                  test: /.scss?$/,
                  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'

                  }

                ]
            },
        };


        Here is my require script located in my app.js file: 

        require('../scss/custom.scss');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to move the loader rule into `module`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'js/bundle.js'
  },

  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        //test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'

      }
    ]
  }
};
```

If that doesn't work, you can try the `use` to specify the loaders:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: It worked!!  The syntax worked.  In addition to not being able to read the @ symbol, I was also having issues with loading all the image files that bootstrap included into the css (i.e. woff, woff2, eot, ttf, svg).  I found a tutorial that addressed the image issue (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vZrWNWrEsU).  With the new syntax you provided and loading the URL-loader for the images, I was able to resolve both issues.   Thank you!!